# how to call MobileAds.initialize properly in android?

Tags: android, ads

I am using a listener on `MobileAds.initialize` so that it calls `Interstitial_Show` and `Interstitial_SHOW` in `onInitializationComplete`

```
            MobileAds.initialize(context, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
                Log.d("update_statut","onInitializationComplete"+initializationStatus);
                mCallbackTwo.onClickTwo("Interstitial_LOAD");
                mCallback.onClick("Interstitial_SHOW");
            }
        });
```

> Splash Activity

```
@Override
public void onClickTwo(String value) { Interstitial_LOAD();  }


@Override
public void onClick(String value ) {
if (!isFinishing()){
    Handler handler1 = new Handler();
    handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
    if( (!jsonfetch.check_version) && jsonfetch.isupdated){
        update_dialog();
        Log.d("update_statut", "Update dialog ");
    } else {
        Log.d("update_statut", "Interstitial_SHOW");
        Interstitial_SHOW();
    }
        } 
         }, 5000);
} else  Log.d("update_statut", "isFinishing : TRUE");
}


    private void Interstitial_LOAD()  {
        AdRequest adRequestI = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId(inter_code);
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequestI);
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                Log.d("update_statut", "onAdClosed , Start first_java Activity");
                startActivity(new Intent(splash.this, first_java.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION));
                splash.this.finish();
            }
        });
    }

private void Interstitial_SHOW() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
            return;
        }
        Log.d("update_statut", "interstitial is not loaded in splash , Start first_java Activity");
        startActivity(new Intent(splash.this, first_java.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION));
        splash.this.finish();
}
```

**I would like to know if this is a safe way ( to put the startActivity code in the Initialization Listener )**

**What are the cases when the Initialization can't be completed ? ( what if the admob has been suspended for example )**

**Is there any Listener triggers when Initialization is not completed ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/MobileAds#initialize(android.content.Context,java.lang.String)) , calling initialize will :

> Initializes the Google Mobile Ads SDK.

My guess is that it will setup the SDK with your publisher id, other realative static information and your ad settings to make your first request faster..

However, you can actually forget to initialize your SDK and your requests will still work because these information will fetched when you make your first request according to the documentation:

> If this method is not called, the first ad request automatically initializes the Google Mobile Ads SDK.

So I would say switch your focus to your ad requests by implementing an **AdListener** . In case you are not served an ad it will inform you that and the reason for that which might be as you said (suspended account) or another reason.

This is how to [implement your AdListener](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner?hl=en#ad_events) just in case:

```
mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdOpened() {
        // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
        // covers the screen.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClicked() {
        // Code to be executed when the user clicks on an ad.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLeftApplication() {
        // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        // Code to be executed when the user is about to return
        // to the app after tapping on an ad.
    }
});
```

Comment: If this method is not called, the first ad request automatically initializes the Google Mobile Ads SDK. This is helpful , thank you